# How to design a voltage follower/Unity gain buffer circuit using MOSFET?

Tags: analog, cmos, buffer

I am trying to design a voltage follower to drive a resistive load using MOSFET as a peripheral circuit. I am using this simple circuit using two NMOS transistors. The output is following the input. But the problem is output is becoming load-dependent. If I change the resistance of the load, I am getting an increase/decrease in output voltage.
How can I solve this problem?
Is there any CMOS based stable voltage follower/Unity gain buffer circuit which can be used to drive a resistive load?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6sinI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: If you incorporate an op-amp and take feedback from Vout you can make it basically load independent.

Comment: @mkeith Thank you for your comment. I have area and power constraints so I cannot use op-amp. Are there any other ways or any other CMOS based circuits?

Comment: If you can't use an opamp, then a single NPN will give better results than a single MOSFET.

Comment: @Mattman944 Thank you. I will check if this works.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an op-amp to provide feedback control to mostly eliminate the load dependence:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLb5Oi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In comments you said the reason you have not considered using an op-amp is "I have area and power constraints". But your proposed solution is to use a second MOSFET.

Very likely you can find an op-amp that uses just as little area and less power than any solution that involves adding a second MOSFET.

For example, Mouser lists 215 op-amps in SC70-5 package (2.0 x 1.25 mm), with typical supply current as low as 350 nA (and almost all below 1 mA). Other options are available in packages (mostly "wafer-level" and "chip-scale" types) smaller than 1 x 1 mm.

The best choice of op-amp will depend on the required bandwidth and Vdd voltage, which you haven't shared.

Comment: Upvoted because I agree 100%. Packaged op-amps can be just as small as packaged transistors, because it is the package, not the die that is limiting size. I do suggest a series resistor to the gate, and a feedback capacitor from the op-amp output (which may not be needed, but...).

Comment: @mkeith, like so?

Comment: Yeah but now that I see it I realize that the cap can't do much because vout will likely be low impedance. The cap will be "swamped". Maybe add a resistor between Vout and the bottom of the cap to allow it to have some effect. The concern is that the op-amp may not be stable if it takes its feedback from the transistor output. Taking some feedback directly from the op-amp output was intended to stabilize it (I mean that was my motivation).

Comment: @mkeith, careful, though. If we add too many extra parts OP's concerns about board area might start to gain some validity.

Comment: Yes. Maybe better to just go to BJT instead of mosfet and get rid of the capacitor. I think the BJT will make a nicer load for the op-amp rather than the possibly high capacitance gate of the MOSFET.

Comment: @ThePhoton  Thank you for your comment. Actually, I am using 65nm CMOS technology node to design the peripheral circuit and the Vdd voltage is 2.5V. I think I need to use CMOS based opamp.

Comment: @mkeith Thank you for your comment. I am looking for driver circuits that are used to drive memories. I will try with BJT too. Won't BJT increase the power consumption?

Comment: The BJT and MOSFET are very comparable when used this way (as a voltage follower). There is a little bit of current supplied to the base of the BJT that could be considered wasted current (compared to the MOSFET), but it will be around 1 or 2 percent of the resistor current, so very minimal difference.